# What's wrong with my implementation of RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am following the Android Developer's explanatin on how to set RecyclerView, but I get some errors, for example `android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView`.

The code taken from here : [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)

This is my code, including all necessary files:

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.lastlocation.recyclerviewer;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

        // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
        // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        // use a linear layout manager
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        String[] myDataset = new String[5];
        myDataset[0] = "Data0";
        myDataset[1] = "Data1";
        myDataset[2] = "Data2";
        myDataset[3] = "Data3";
        myDataset[4] = "Data4";

        // specify an adapter (see also next example)
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(myDataset);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
}
```

This is MyAdapter.java:

```
package com.example.lastlocation.recyclerviewer;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private String[] mDataset;

    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView mTextView;
        public MyViewHolder(TextView v) {
            super(v);
            mTextView = v;
        }
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public MyAdapter(String[] myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                     int viewType) {


        TextView v = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, parent, false);

        MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element
        holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset[position]);

    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.length;
    }
}
```

this is activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="386dp"
        android:layout_height="135dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="66dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view"
        app:srcCompat="@android:color/holo_orange_dark" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="68dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="John Doe"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />


    <!-- A RecyclerView with some commonly used attributes -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="375dp"
        android:layout_height="367dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.428"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is the xml for a single text view called my_text_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<!-- Layout for a single list item -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/my_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />


    </LinearLayout>
```

As you can see I nearly copied the code from the Android Developer's website, but I still don't know where is the problem.

Comment: In Your `single list item`  the hight of your `LinearLayout` should be **`wrap_content`** like `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Comment: I keep getting the same error, do you mind testing it yourself to see maybe for you it does work? For me it didn't. Thanks

Comment: `TextView v = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()) .inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, parent, false);` - it's clear from your code that the root tag for `my_text_view` is a `LinearLayout`, not `TextView`, so of course you will get a casting exception

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView mTextView;
        public MyViewHolder(TextView v) {
            super(v);
            mTextView = v;
        }
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public MyAdapter(String[] myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }
```

The problem is in your ViewHolder constructor it should be like that

```
public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView mTextView;
        public MyViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            mTextView = v.findViewById(R.id.your_text_view_id);
        }
    }


 @Override
    public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                     int viewType) {


        View v = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, parent, false);

        MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }
```

You are trying to assign LinearLayout which is the View in your constructor to your TextView and it is crashing. This will fix the problem.
The view you receive as a constructor param in your ViewHolder is the root view of your ViewHolder, in your case a LinearLayout, from this root view you can find the other views in it.

Answer (score 0):

You are inflating row view wrongly and thus not assigning views in viewholder in proper manner change your code as below

```
@Override
    public UserListAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder((inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_row_layout, parent, false)));
        return vh;
    }
```

and change your viewholder as below

```
public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView mTextView;
        public MyViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            mTextView = v.findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Simply you need to change your onCreateViewHolder method by taking as

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, parent, false);
return view;
```

Comment: You only removed the `(TextView)`? Btw the other answer worked (To only have the TextView in the xml file

Comment: but you are using only one textview in your custom layout,when you use more than one textview or button then it shows error ,So you need to put your textview  in one layout(linear,relative or constraint layout) and inflate your layout in View class in your method.